# Map n states to hardwired outputs

Tags: design

I'm still new to the world of electronics, so forgive me if the question is too simple.
What I'm trying to do is build a component which takes `n` wires, of which only one at a time (or none) will be powered. It is connected to a 7-segments display: each state corresponds to a letter on the display.
This is the design I'm using:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5gJ5j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I see a potential issue: when one of the input wires is triggered, the signal also flows "backwards", specifically in all the wires which share at least one output with the original wire [It's hard to explain with words, you might understand looking at the picture.]
I definitely want to avoid this effect. However, the only solution I can think of is placing diodes between one insertion and another, which is not possible due to scarcity of materials (this is a school project thing, so I'm likely to have access to 10-12 diodes).
Are there more resources-efficient methods to achieve this?

I'm using 9V DC current. The wires will be triggered on or off at low frequencies, since it will rely on hand-operated switches to control current flow.

Comment: Regarding the "backwards flow", indeed you need diodes to block it. I'm afraid it's the cheaper/simpler solution. Otherwise you need an IC, either some form for microcontroller or dedicated IC (7 segment decoder).

Comment: If this is a LED 7 segment display (which is not specified) do mind whether it is common anode or common cathode.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to use more complex chips you will indeed need diodes. A simple one like a 1N4148 will do. You will need quite a few of them, but luckily they are cheap.

Note that you will also need current limiting resistors in series with each segment of your display. 1k would be a good guess.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a design which involves fewer diodes?

Comment: Yes, using one or two chips (priority encoder + binary-to-7segments decoder). Or, what most people today would do: take a microcontroller. But that requires that you know how to program it.